# D3 Transitions -- Transition of exit() selection fails

Tags: d3.js, transition

**I have a pretty straightforward D3 use case:**

- A user is presented with several boxes containing information
- On pressing an "update" button, new data is bound to the collection of boxes (divs), resulting in one box exiting and one new box entering.
- I want to animate the enter, update, and exit selections

Currently, I schedule a transition on my exit selection with a delay of 5 seconds while the transition on my merged update selection (including the appended enter selection) runs immediately and with a duration of 4.5 seconds.

The update transition is "chained"--I schedule a second transition on each element in the update selection using transition.each() and listening for the "end" event.

**The problem:**

If the user clicks "update" rapidly two or more times, the exit() transition fails to complete, resulting in boxes remaining on screen.

I can't figure out why this is happening--it's not obvious to me how the transition on my exiting elements gets overridden.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yw8qmdLe/3/

Thanks in advance!

**JavaScript:**

```
  var dat = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

  var svg = d3.select("#main");
  svg.selectAll("div.box").data(dat).enter().append("div").attr("class","box").text(function(d,i){return d});

  var button = d3.select("#button")
  button.on("mousedown",function(){
    dat.push(dat[dat.length-1] + 1);
    dat.shift();

    var update = svg.selectAll("div.box").data(dat,function(d,i){return d});
    update.style("border-left","0px solid #0000ff").text(function(d,i){return d + ": update"});


    update.enter().append("div").attr("class","box").text(function(d,i){return d + ": enter"}).style("border-left","0px solid #00ff00");
    update.exit()
    .style("border-left","40px solid #000000")
    .text(function(d,i){
      return d + ": exit";
    }).transition().delay(5000).duration(1000)
    .style("width",function(d,i){
      //console.log(this.__transition__);
      return "0px";
    })
    .style("border-left-width","0px")
    .text("")
    .remove();

    update.transition().duration(4500).style("border-left-width","40px").each("end",function(d,i){
      d3.select(this).transition().duration(700).style("border-left-width","0px")
    })

  })
```

Comment: Transitions are stored as part of the DOM element's attributes. As soon as a new transition is added to the element, the old transition is lost. What happens in your case is that the elements that were in the exit selection (for which the transition is still running) are in either the update or exit selection again and a new transition is added, cancelling the old one.

Comment: I understand that newer transitions override older ones. In this case, an element that gets included in an exit selection should never again appear in an update selection (because of the key function I've used here). If a previously exiting element has a new transition scheduled because it is in a newer exit selection, then I'd expect that newer transition to take care of the removal of the element.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the "end" event that is causing your problem. Honestly not sure why. My theory would be that click on the update button the second time cancels active transitions resulting in the "end" event firing and applying the new transition, which wipes out the exit transition so the .remove() call is never reached.

Comment: Ethan, I think you are right that the "end" event is causing the issue: On the initial click, the first element gets added to the exit selection and a transition is scheduled (with a delay) that culminates in a remove(). On the second click, the second element is added to another exit selection (with a delay). But due to the delay, the previously running transition continues to run. That transition finishes and its "end" event is dispatched, which produces another transition. Somewhere in the middle of that transition is when the delayed exit transition should start.

Comment: However, it never does... Presumably because the transition initiated from within the "end" event is newer than any other scheduled transition. My reading of the documentation (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#each) suggested that this shouldn't be the case due to the fact that multi-staged transitions like this are considered to be of one age (that of the original transition).

Comment: You don't actually need the `.each("end", ...)` here -- simply chaining the transitions is equivalent (http://jsfiddle.net/yw8qmdLe/20/). This also fixes the error, so yes, it is indeed the end event handler. What's happening is that the update transition starts, then (when you click again) the exit transition is scheduled (not run), but before it has a chance to run, it is overridden by the end handler of the update transition that was still there from the previous button click.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've switched to using the transition().transition() pattern, which works (though I wish the documentation was a little more explicit as to why one works and the other doesn't).

Comment: Just closing the loop on this one... I ran across this note in "Working With Transitions" (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/): "Prior to 3.0, transitions inherited the id when a new transition was created inside the end event listener. This has been removed in favor of chained transitions." So I tried my example out with an old version of D3 (http://jsfiddle.net/yw8qmdLe/24/) and I don't encounter the problem. Clearly, transition.transition() is the preferred pattern now.